# I have to prove by mathematical induction that $\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1) !}$ is a natural number for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: induction

I have to prove by mathematical induction that $$\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1) !}$$ is a natural number for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Any help would be really awesome.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I don't know what i have to show, I stardet to calculate what my expresion is and  I just get lost in the problem. Basically, I don't know where to begin or what to try to show.

Comment: Did you calculate a base case?

Comment: Well, for $n=1$ the problem is true because $\frac{2!}{1! \cdot 2!}=1$ and $1\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Ever heard about induction? Give it a try!

Comment: Now assume it is true for the $n$ case and prove it is true for the $n+1$ case.

Comment: These are called Catalan numbers,fwiw,

Comment: @Karl -- this is actually not as trivial as it seems, I'd say. For a start, IIRC (I may be wrong, but from my high school memories) one has to use strong induction for Catalan numbers (it does not just follow from the the one or two previous terms).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may try to do induction backwardly.

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$ be the smallest integer such that 
$$
\frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!} = \frac{a}{b}
$$
for some $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(a,b) = 1$ and $a > b$.
(Here $n > 1$ because if $n=1$ then the quotient = 1.)
Then
$$
\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!n!} 
=
\frac{(2n-1)(2n)n(n+1)(2n-2)!}{n(n+1)(2n-1)(2n)(n-1)!n!}
=
\frac{n(n+1)}{(2n-1)(2n)}\frac{a}{b} = \frac{n+1}{4n-2}\frac{a}{b} = k
$$
for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Thus $k = 1$.
But then
$$
\frac{4n-2}{n+1} = \frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!} = \frac{(2n)\cdots (n+1)}{(n+1)!},
$$
i.e.
$$
1 = \frac{(2n-2)(2n-3)\cdots (n+1)}{(n-1)!},
$$
so $n=1$,
a contradiction.

Comment: Hi @BrianM.Scott, thank you. Yes, though the result is unchanged, my previous version is not clear at the point.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, it is quite easy *without* induction:
We know that ${n\choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ is always an integer (namely the *number* off ways to choose $k$ elements from a set of $n$ elements)  and have $$ \frac{(2n)!}{n!(n+1)!}=\frac1{n+1}{2n\choose n}=\frac{1}{2n+1}{2n+1\choose n}.$$
Hence if we write the expression  as fraction $\frac ab$ in shortest terms then $b\mid n+1$ and $b\mid 2n+1$. As $\gcd(n+1,2n+1)=1$, the claim follows.

Comment: Even easier without induction - see the Wikipedia page for Catalan numbers.